# OpenSSL: Get CMS_SignerInfo as DER Encoded ASN.1 data

Tags: c, openssl, content-management-system

with Openssl I can get a `CMS_SignerInfo` from a CMS container.
I can then use

```
CMS_SignerInfo_get0_signer_id(CMS_SignerInfo *si, ASN1_OCTET_STRING **keyid, X509_NAME **issuer, ASN1_INTEGER **sno);
```

to obtain either the keyid or issuer and serialnumber of the certificate.

What I am looking for is a way to obtain the entire ASN.1 set of the SignerIdentifier containing the Sequence of issuer and serial number.
Is there a way in openssl or will I have to use the aforementioned function to obtain the single elements and then rebuild the ASN.1 structure with the openssl API?